Page hangs when using Selenium IDE extension in both Edge as well as Chrome
When using Selenium IDE to identify Xpath locators of website components for robot framework automatic testing purposes, my browser always hangs after a couple of seconds. The IDE will record some of the activity but then stumbles. I get a 'Code hung' error in the browser and a popup that the page is not responding; waiting does not help, it stays hung and needs to be closed. The issue happens in both Chrome as Edge. Colleagues who use the same hardware setups do not experience this issue. Any ideas as to the cause(s)?
Thanks already.
enter image description here
The issue is also not page related, I can reproduce it on e.g. amazon.com, as well as my work-related application websites.

Have you tried disabling all your other browser addins? Something seems to be different about your machine.

Can you reproduce on different hardware yourself? What about software? We need to see a [mcve] to assist further here; too much information is missing.
